# Regex with positive lookahead across multiple lines

Tags: regex, macos, pcre, regex-lookarounds, textwrangler

I've been trying to isolate blocks containing a certain string in TextWrangler.

Here is the sample I'm working with.

```
<ROW num="381">
  <TO>8549672167</TO>
  <FROM>8936742582</FROM>
  <TIME>5/10/2009 19:49:3</TIME>
  <TEXT>Blah Blah Blah</TEXT>
</ROW>
<ROW num="382">
  <TO>8549672167</TO>
  <FROM>8591903412</FROM>
  <TIME>5/10/2009 19:49:37</TIME>
  <TEXT>Hme</TEXT>
</ROW>
```

What I'm trying to do is isolate all multi-line blocks beginning with `<ROW` and ending with `</ROW>`that contain the digits `412`in the line beginning `<FROM>`

So in the above example, the second block would be highlighted, but not the first.

I have no idea where to begin with is, can anybody help?
Thanks, MS.

Comment: your 2nd ROW's <TO> doesn't contain 412   FROM does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ROW[^<]*?>[^<]*<TO>(?=[^<]*412)[^<]*<\/TO>.*?<\/ROW>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1UQl9g/4)

[image]

> **Updated answer as per op's updated question and comment :**

```
<ROW(?=((?!ROW).)*<FROM>\d*412\d*<\/FROM>).*?<\/ROW>
```

[Updated Link For Explanation and Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1UQl9g/6)

Comment: Hi this seems to work except that when it finds an instance, it highlights from that instance's "<ROW" all the way to the end of the sample text instead of terminating at the next "</ROW" and continuing on to find the next instance.

Comment: Actually this works if you add a "?" after the final asterisk! Is there anyway I can do the same type of search but for the "<FROM>" line. I've tried substituting FROM for TO but that doesn't yield anything. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to cause a "catastrophic backtracking". I tried to read up on that but it went straight over my head. It seems to work in the example you provided but when I paste in the rest of the sample, it provides the aforementioned error.

Comment: in your updated example, that negative lookahead within the positive lookahead blew my mind. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
<ROW.*>[\s\n]*<TO>.*412.*<\/TO>[\w\d\s\n<>\/:]*<\/ROW>
```

url : http://regexr.com/3f1e7

i update the solution to contain 412 in tag TO

hope this helps

Comment: If contains special character, then it will not work

Comment: Sorry this does not seem to work, it seems to highlight the whole sample if it finds any instance of 412 in a <TO> line.

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt yes, wasnt perfect answer

Comment: @user7397354 in what case? tested and working correctly in regexr